# JavaScript Split Array on Dot

Tags: javascript, arrays, split

I have a Javascript Array that contains the file name and its extension such as this:

```
let files = ["Apple.docx", "Cat.jpeg", "Moon.gif"];
```

I want to make it so the extensions like (.docx, .jpeg and .gif) are stored in another array and also uppercase as this while the original array just becomes:

```
let files = ["Apple", "Cat", "Moon"];
let extensions = ['DOCX', 'JPEG', 'GIF'];
```

Comment: use `split()` inside `for` loop or `map`;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use [String.split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) method.
About extension, you can use [String.toUpperCase()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toUpperCase).

```js
const files = ["Apple.docx", "Cat.jpeg", "Moon.gif"];
const names = [], extensions = [];

files.forEach(name => {
  const splitted = name.split(".");
  names.push(splitted[0]);
  extensions.push(splitted[1].toUpperCase());
});

console.log(names, extensions);
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
const extensions = [];

const files = ["Apple.docx", "Cat.jpeg", "Moon.gif"].map(x => {
  const idx = x.lastIndexOf(".");
  if (idx === -1) {
    extensions.push("");
    return x;
  }
  extensions.push(x.substring(idx + 1).toUpperCase());
  return x.substring(0, idx);
});

console.log(files);
console.log(extensions);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let files = ["Apple.docx", "Cat.jpeg", "Moon.gif"];
extensions = files.map(e => (e.split('.')[1]).toUpperCase())

console.log(extensions)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
let files = ["Apple.docx", "Cat.jpeg", "Moon.gif"];
let extensions = [];
let newFiles = [];
files.map((val)=>{
    newFiles.push(val.split('.')[0]); // files name without extension
    extensions.push(val.split('.')[1]); // extensions of files.
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is one of the ways using [`String.split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split), [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) & [`Destructuring assignment`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) in order to achieve the expected output.

```js
let files = ["Apple.docx", "Cat.jpeg", "Moon.gif"];

const formatFiles = files => {
  return files.reduce((res, file) => {
  //split and assign the values using destructuring assignment
    const [name, ext] = file.split(".");
    res.names.push(name);
    res.exts.push(ext.toUpperCase());
    return res;
  }, {names: [], exts:[]});
}

console.log(formatFiles(files));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```